# Wen I click on a movie it still apears the lsit of movies . PHP

Tags: php, arrays, list, hyperlink

So I was making a PHP site and it's done but I want to change something  , when I click on one movie  I don't want to still show me the list of movies I want only the details about that movie and the 'back to home' button.I greatly appreciate your help.

```
<?php 

    //An array ith movies
    $movies = array();
    $movies[1] = array(
                        'title' => 'The Godfather',
                        'year'  => 1972, 
                        'poster'=> 'images/godfather.jpg');
    $movies[2] = array(
                        'title' => 'Pulp fiction',
                        'year'  => 1994, 
                        'poster'=> 'images/pulpfiction.jpg');
    $movies[3] = array(
                        'title' => 'Life is beautiful',
                        'year'  => 1997, 
                        'poster'=> 'images/life.jpg');
    $movies[4] = array(
                        'title' => 'Goodfellas', 
                        'year'  => 1990, 
                        'poster'=> 'images/goodfellas.jpg');
    $movies[5] = array(
                        'title' => 'The Shawshank Redemption', 
                        'year'  => 1994, 
                        'poster'=> 'images/theshawshankredemption.jpg');
    $movies[6] = array(
                        'title' => 'The Dark Knight',
                        'year'  => 2008,
                        'poster'=> 'images/thedarkknight.jpg');
    $movies[7] = array(
                        'title' => '12 Angry Men',
                        'year'  => 1957,
                        'poster'=> 'images/angrymen.jpg');
    $movies[8] = array(
                        'title' => 'Schindler'."'".'s List',
                        'year'  => 1993,
                        'poster'=> 'images/schindlerslist.jpg');
    $movies[9] = array(
                        'title' => 'Fight Club',
                        'year'  => 1999,
                        'poster'=> 'images/fightclub.jpg');
    $movies[10] = array(
                        'title' => 'Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back',
                        'year'  => 1980,
                        'poster'=> 'images/starwarsv.jpg');
    $movies[11] = array(
                        'title' => 'Inception',
                        'year'  => 2010,
                        'poster'=> 'images/inception.jpg');
    //print('<pre>');
    //print_r($movies);




    echo "<h1>My movies</h1>\n";
    echo "<ul>\n";
    for ($i=1; $i < count($movies); $i++) { 
        $movie_title = $movies[$i]['title'];
        print('<li><a href="movies.php?movie=' . $i . '">' . $movie_title . "</a></li>\n");
    }
    echo "</ul>\n"; 


    //make sure exists .
    if (isset($_GET['movie'])) {
        $movie_position_in_array = $_GET['movie'];
        print($movie_position_in_array);


    //test
    $movie_position_in_array = $_GET['movie'];
    $movie_details = $movies[$movie_position_in_array];


    //Display all movie details
    $movie_position_in_array = $_GET['movie'];
    $movie_details = $movies[$movie_position_in_array];
    print('<h1>'. $movie_details['title']. '</h1>');
    print('<h2>'. $movie_details['year']. '</h2>');
    print('<img src="' . $movie_details['poster'] . '">');


    //give users a link
    print('<p><a href="movies.php">Back to movies</a></p>');

    } 
    else {
        echo '<p>---------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>';
    } 





    ?>
```

Comment: Okay, and what do you expect from us? We aren't gonna code it for you.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yaaas  i did all till now and now i'm stuck here i dont know how to do'it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well one way is you can make a cookie and save the array in there. So post this at the bottom of your web page. or anywhere below your movies array.

```
$json = json_encode($movies);
setcookie('movies', $json);
```

Then on your movies.php webpage just access the cookie array.

```
<?PHP

$i = (int) htmlspecialchars($_GET['movie']);

$cookie = $_COOKIE['movies'];
$cookie = stripslashes($cookie);
$movies= json_decode($cookie, true);

var_dump ($movies[$i]);

?>
```